# Why the "" BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null "" happened when BLE Scan in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing in Android for BLE. My BLE device will broadcast for different name , so I need to continue re-scan Android.

I create a `Runnable` to stop and start scan like the following. When I call `mHandler.post(monitorDevice);` , it will start the `Runnable`.

```
final Runnable monitorDevice = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scanLeDevice(false);
        scanLeDevice(true);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this,3000);
    }
};
```

The code of `scanLeDevice` is like the following:

```
public void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(enable){
                    mScanning = true;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                }else {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }
```

I can see the scan result in the log at the begin. But after about 10~15 minute , the logcat show the following log , and I can not seen any scan result.

```
startLeScan(): null
D/BluetoothLeScanner﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
```

Does someone has this problem ? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same issue. And after a period, call startLeScan() will block 10 seconds, and return false.

Comment: Was this ever solved? same issue, it will work fine for a time then just start outputting that over and over again

Comment: I had similar issue, found the solution on SO. You'll see there a refresh of the cache related to connections, yet it solved other items as above (scanning). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596951/how-to-programmatically-force-bluetooth-low-energy-service-discovery-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568932/blutooth-le-scan